# AMD v/s intel. Advice needed

Tags: cpu, dell-inspiron

I am about to purchase a dell laptop with AMD Phenom(TM) II Quad-Core Mobile Processor N930. When I asked which is the equivalent intel processor the reply was i5. Please suggest me if its comparable to the latest processors released by intel or not.

Comment: http://www.notebookcheck.net/AMD-Phenom-II-X4-N930-Notebook-Processor.31536.0.html

Comment: @Aki not very great information.

Comment: answered, but i'd note that this is a fairly time sensitive/localised question. it'll only really be useful till the next refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a little like apples and oranges - the AMD seems to [benchmark](http://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu_lookup.php?cpu=AMD%20Phenom%20II%20N930%20Quad-Core) fairly close to  a generation 2 core i5(a dual core, we'll come to it later), though not everyone agrees with that, [subjectively](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/299960-28-phenom-n930-intel-480m)

I'd suppose in processes that are designed for multithreading, the AMD would have the edge - it has 4 physical cores , for processes that need more power for a single thread, the intel may have the edge - especially since it can overclock individual cores - its dual core with hyperthreading.

Comment: Is Hyperthreading generally considered a good thing these days?  I remember a few years ago when the HT benchmarks showed worse performance than with it disabled in some tests... is that still true?

Comment: not any more. More cores = better multithreaded performance than HT but HT is better than non HT, i think... yanno, that would be a VERY good SU question IMO :)